# Автозапуск программ на python

Tags: автозапуск

Я хочу запускать программу при включение windows, но если добавлять программу сразу в папку автозапуска то антивирусы ругаются мол это вирус. Какой можно еще использовать метод?

Comment: Например, удалить этот тупой антивирус?

Comment: Без него никак.

Answer (score 1):

Создай ярлык к python.exe. В свойствах ярлыка укажи в рабочую папку папку проекта. После python.exe допиши имя запускаемого py файла.

Comment: а для чайника???

Comment: так это и есть для чайника))